# How could I add drag and drop functionality for the design of a restaurant's floor plan/table layout?

Tags: javascript, html, web-development, css, jquery

I'm doing my first web application, it is for managing restaurants. One of the functionalities I would like it to have, is the ability to design the table layout by dragging and dropping tables from a toolbar somewhere in the screen. I would like to have a way of storing the table's position so that it remains the same if close the app. I would also like the tables to be clickable, so that then the waiters can click them and interact with them to open/close them, charge items that customers order, print the check, etc.

Is there a library or framework that would allow me to do something like that?

Comment: Are you getting anywhere with this? As you know, I am also interested in the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Have you done any research? I too would like an answer to this. I have, as yet, found no library, but the following have helped me greatly:

- W3C Schools have a [simple working demo](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp), with documentation
- Tutorial Point's [documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_drag_drop.htm)
- [Mozilla's Drag & Drop documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API)
- [A good tutorial](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/)

You ought to be ok, since you just want predefined shapes, so it will be easy enough to have a toolbar with squares, circles, etc, which can be dragged to your floorplan.  I have a problem because I want the user to be able to re-shape the dragged items, which represent rooms.

Let us know if you need more help. If you ***do*** find a good library or framework, please post an answer and accept it, to help others in future.

---

[Update] I guess that I was not looking seriously before. All of these frameworks seem acceptable:

- http://interactjs.io/
- https://bevacqua.github.io/dragula/
- http://www.infragistics.com/samples/aspnet/drag-drop-framework/overview

### Related

- [What is the best JavaScript framework to implement a drag and drop customizable website builder?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-JavaScript-framework-to-implement-a-drag-and-drop-customizable-website-builder)
- [Choosing a javascript MVC framework for a drag and drop interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761981/choosing-a-javascript-mvc-framework-for-a-drag-and-drop-interface)
- [Touch-friendly Drag and Drop](https://mobiforge.com/design-development/touch-friendly-drag-and-drop)

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! I'll look into all of these. I had done some research, but clearly not as thoroughly or effectively as you did. Thanks!

Comment: I have *a lot* more. I will sort through them & post the best. Once you have drawn your floorpan, consider how you are going to save it and reload it for edtting later