# Dynamic Floor Plans in Web App

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, svg

I am developing a web-based restaurant management system for several different venues and need to implement dynamic floor plans for table management. The tables need to be clickable and editable, the different floor plans need to be stored, not sure whether to store them in the database or as images?

I am currently stuck after looking at several options:

- Canvas-suboptimal
- Svg- manipulating svg file with JS seems most suitable, not sure which library to use.
- Jquery UI - using Bootstrap and the two don't play nice together

What would you recommend for my specific case? Which JS library to use with Svg?

Comment: I don't think you need a separate library for manipulating SVG with JavaScript. SVG is a subset of XML, so shouldn't the usual DOM manipulation tools suffice?

Comment: Realted question :   https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/39960/how-could-i-add-drag-and-drop-functionality-for-the-design-of-a-restaurants-flo

Comment: Well, I saw several other questions discussing using something like D3.js or Raphaël.js. I do not have experience with Svg manipulation, so would appreciate any advice about best practices.

Answer (score 1):

[Essential Diagram for JavaScript](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/ejdiagram) supports manipulating SVG based nodes and serialization.

[Example](http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/uj0uyfqc)

[image: Diagram JS with SVG nodes]

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: I can't find full version of this example. Please provide it if you can.

Comment: @ІгорЖовтанюк Did you visit http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/uj0uyfqc - you can get the full source for the sample from there - the library itself needs to be downloaded from http://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/ejdiagram